# How to run "php artisan serve" on same port for multiple Laravel projects

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

as I see its not possible to serve two laravel projects on same port
for example:

```
php artisan server --port=80 --host=somedomain.com
php artisan server --port=80 --host=anotherdomain.com
```

if there is any solution for this issue, tell me that.

regards

Comment: What are you using?  xampp? homestead?

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan serve` will start a normal webserver for just this project. If you want to run the in parallel, you need a webserver like nginx oder apache. The you create a config for every project and point to the public folder. All projects are accessible via port 80, but with a different domain.